# Export Modelsim waveform as image from command-line

Tags: simulation, waveform, modelsim

Is there a way to export Modelsim/VCS waveforms as images (png, jpeg or SVG)?

Currently the only method I know of is to fire up the simulator, run the simulation and then either do a Print Screen or File->Export Wave in Modelsim.

Is it possible to do this from the command line? I want to be able to script it through TCL or bash.

Note that I'm not limiting myself to these simulators. Is it possible to convert VCD files to images at all?

Comment: I think GTKWave can display VCS dumps. I don't know what formats it can export.

Comment: It can. I cant find a way to export them through a script or command line though.